# Why different result of a function?

Tags: r

Why i got different string input when running this two almost similar  commands (except for the start of the string)

```
substr(getURL(paste("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/4a9f52/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls")),10,90)
```

In this i have only ces in as output

```
substr(getURL(paste("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/4a9f52/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls")),80,90)
```

Comment: Because the arguments are different. The first command `substr(..., 10,90)` gives you a substring from the 10th character to the 90th character. The second command `substr(..., 80,90)` starts at the 80th character and goes to the 90th character. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Also why are you taking a substring of an excel file??

Comment: For the first code I got "\n\t<body>\r\n\t\t<table>\r\n\t\t\t<thead>\r\n\t\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<td colspan=\"24\">Elspot Prices in", and for 2nd "ef=\"/4aa9e9". So you can see that first code should include chars from the second, however it is not

Comment: Ah, that would be very good information to include in your question. I'd suggest editing your question to highlight that confusion.

Comment: Perhaps you could also show something that should encompass both... like what does `substr(..., 1, 150)` give?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the results you describe. I do get the behavior you expect. I’d suspect, that the second http request goes wrong for you in some way. Did you repeatedly get the same results?

```r
substr(RCurl::getURL(paste("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/4a9f52/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls")),10,90)
#> [1] "ad><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"/4aa9e9"
substr(RCurl::getURL(paste("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/4a9f52/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls")),80,90)
#> [1] "t Prices in"
```

In order not to download the data for each operation, you could store the data first, like this:

```r
a <- RCurl::getURL("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/4a9f52/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_2020_hourly_eur.xls")

substr(a, 10, 90)
#> [1] "\n\t<body>\r\n\t\t<table>\r\n\t\t\t<thead>\r\n\t\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<td colspan=\"24\">Elspot Prices in"
substr(a, 80, 90)
#> [1] "t Prices in"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>